# In MySQL table update 'a' record  with 'b' and 'b' with 'a'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

In my table there are two field, one is name and other is gender. I want to fire query so that 
every male is update with female and viceversa.

I don't want to use procedure, trigger or function. I have to do this only with simple query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MSSQL you could do this:

```
UPDATE table SET gender = CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 'F' ELSE 'M' END
```

If there is anything similar is My-SQL then this is one easy statement.

Answer (score 4):

Make it a three step.

-- Step 1: Give the males a temporary gender value (gender X)

-- Step 2: Set the female records to male (F to M)

-- Step 3: Set the old male records to
    female (**X** to F)

```
Update table Set Gender = 'X' where Gender = 'M'
Update table Set Gender = 'M' where Gender = 'F'
Update table Set Gender = 'F' where Gender = 'X'
```

Comment: is there any other solution that we are require to write three query.

Answer (score 0):

For numerical values:

#logic

```
a = b - a;
b = b - a;
a = b + a;
```

#mysql

```
UPDATE tbl t SET t.a = t.b - t.a, t.b = t.b - t.a, t.a = t.b + t.a WHERE t.b < t.a;
```

changes a to b, b to a... if b < a;